# Show content of map during debugging a different dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, stl

I have a program with several classes and dlls/exe:

In the dll I have a map with several objects which are accessed from other dlls and exes.

When debugging the dll with the map I can see the contents:
[image]

During debugging in those other dlls I can't see the content of the map (only ...):
[image]

Am I experiencing the Microsoft Problem that STL classes can't be exported (C4251)? I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update2

How would you deal with this? In the end I want to have a repository which holds different objects and their parent/child relations between them. Seeing the relations everywhere during debugging would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding template instantiation for all missing types. These have to be written without declspec(dllexport) or extern so now I have a bunch of

`template class std::unordered_map<const Parent*, std::vector<Child*>>;`

in my Repo.h. I also had to add /bigobj to cl.exe